# How to escape the & in an Outlook MailItem attachment display name

Tags: c#, outlook, escaping, mailitem

We have clients that contain an & in their name (e.g. A&W Rootbeer, etc). When we try to combine the client name with other verbiage, it either converts the & to an underline in the next letter or escapes and replaces it with a back slash. I'm guessing this pertains to menu items and things of that nature where an & represents a hot key and is intentionally converted to an underline of the next letter. Any ideas on how to correctly escape the & so that it displays properly?

Answer (score 0):

You need to double up the `&` to escape it. For example `A&W Rootbeer` should be `A&&W Rootbeer`.